# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

I am trying to code a simple coinflip type game and when I run it I get the error:

```
if ticket > 50:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'
```

and I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong. For me it seems everything to be fine but when I run it it gives me that error that I previosly wrote. Any help is highly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
def flip():
    if player_ticket > 50:
        if ticket > 50:
            result = Label(mainFrame, text="YOU WON!!!", fg="green")
            result.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
        else:
            result = Label(mainFrame, text="YOU LOST!!!", fg="red")
            result.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)    

    else:
        if player_ticket < 50:
            if ticket < 50:
                result = Label(mainFrame, text="YOU WON!!!", fg="green")
                result.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
            else:
                result = Label(mainFrame, text="YOU LOST!!!", fg="red")
                result.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)    

def ticket_heads():
    global player_ticket
    player_ticket = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(0, 50))    

def ticket_tails():
    global player_ticket
    player_ticket = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(50, 100))    

def ticket():
    global ticket
    ticket = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(0, 100))    

heads_text = Label(mainFrame, text="Heads")
heads_text.grid(row=0, column=0)    

tails_text = Label(mainFrame, text="Tails")
tails_text.grid(row=0, column=1)    

heads_select = Button(mainFrame, text="Select", command=ticket_heads)
heads_select.grid(row=1, column=0)    

tails_select = Button(mainFrame, text="Select", command=ticket_tails)
tails_select.grid(row=1, column=1)    

flipit = Button(mainFrame, text="Flip It!", command=flip)
flipit.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `ticket` variable gets overwritten by your function variable, `ticket`. Which makes you get an error meaning you can't compare oranges(functions) to apples(integers). Rename either one and it should work fine.

Either replace:

```
global ticket
ticket = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(0, 100))
```

with:

```
global anything_but_ticket
anything_but_ticket = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(0, 100))
```

***or***:

```
def ticket():
```

with:

```
def anything_but_ticket():
```